# I am new to testing in rails. I have Capybara Test for integration But i want to know how to test Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

This is what my current test looks like for sign up

```
RSpec.feature 'Users can sign Up' do
  scenario 'With Valid attributes' do
    visit '/'
    click_link 'Apply'

    expect(page.current_url).to eq new_user_path

    fill_in 'First Name', with: 'John'
    fill_in 'Last Name', with: 'Doe'
    fill_in 'Business Name', with: 'Acme Inc'
    fill_in 'Phone Number', with: '2124567890'
    fill_in 'Cell Number', with: '5202124567'
    fill_in 'Street Address', with: '212 Wise St'
    fill_in 'Apt/Suite', with: '410'
    fill_in 'City', with: 'New york'
    fill_in 'State', with: 'New York'
    fill_in 'Zip-Code', with: '11104'
    fill_in 'Tax ID', with: '12345678'
    fill_in 'SSN', with: '124000987'
    fill_in 'In Business For', with: '5'
    fill_in 'Email', with: 'test@example.com'
    fill_in 'user_password', with: 'password'
    fill_in 'user_password_confirmation', with: 'password'
    click_button 'Submit'

    expect(page.current_url).to eq new_user_document_path
    expect(page).to have_content 'Please Upload documents listed below.'

    attach_file('Upload Document', Rails.root + 'spec/support/files/file.pdf')

    click_button 'Apply'

    expect(page).to have_content 'Thank you for Applying for PetroHub account. We are currently reviewing your application, which might take upto 24hrs.'
  end
```

Now i want to test if User Creation will initiate User Document creation, like for example @user.documents.build or something. 
The test should test if after user creation, Document creation is called and the document is assigned to the user.

Comment: What is your question? You can write model (unit) tests using rspec: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-3/docs/model-specs

Comment: I wanna make sure after "User.create" it goes to "User.documents.build" for that user. During the sign up process.

Comment: Lets say User posts a blog, But after posting a blog you want ot make sure he also post a comment. SO after blog creation it should initiate comment creation.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [controller (functional)](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs) or [request (integration)](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-4/docs/request-specs/request-spec) spec:

```
RSpec.describe UsersController do
  describe "POST /create" do
    let(:valid_attributes) { { foo: 'bar' } }
    let(:invalid_attributes) { { foo: '' } }

    context "with valid attributes" do
      it "creates an associated document" do
        expect {
          post :create, valid_attributes
        }.to change(Document, :count).by(1)

        # or 
        post :create, valid_attributes
        expect(User.last.documents.any?).to be_truthy
      end 
    end

    context "with invalid attributes" do
      it "does not create an associated document" do
        expect {
          post :create, invalid_attributes
        }.to_not change(Document, :count)
      end 
    end
  end
end
```

While it is possible to do the exact same thing in a feature spec, feature specs should orient around the actual user story with as little knowledge of the underlying application as possible.